# How do I change windows in PySimleGui depending on what is selected in sg.Combo?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I need to create a graphical interface for a program that translates mods for a game. The translator has several modes and the input variables are also different. I want the interface to change depending on the one selected in sg.Combo. I wrote code like this:
class with layouts:

```
list_commands = [COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH, COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_RUSSIAN, COMMANDS.TRANSFER_FILE,
                 COMMANDS.ALL_TRANSLATE_DIRECTRY, COMMANDS.TRANSLATE_FILE, COMMANDS.ALL_TRANSFER_DIRECTORY,
                 COMMANDS.STREAMLINE_FILE, COMMANDS.STREAMLINE_DIRECTORY, COMMANDS.SEARCH_UPDATE_STRING_FILE,
                 COMMANDS.SEARCH_UNTRANS_STRING_FILE]

class INTERFACE:
    ADD_FILE_ENG = [[sg.Combo(values=list_commands, key='MODE', default_value=COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH, size=(85, 1), enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Text('Оригинальный файл:', size=(20, 1))],
        [sg.InputText(key='GENERAL_PATH', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
        [sg.Text('Ваш файл:', size=(20, 1))],
        [sg.InputText(key='ADDITIONAL_FILE', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
        [sg.Button(button_text='Выполнить')]]

    ADD_FILE_RU = [[sg.Combo(values=list_commands, key='MODE', default_value=COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_RUSSIAN, size=(85, 1), enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Text('Оригинальный файл:', size=(20, 1))],
        [sg.InputText(key='GENERAL_PATH', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
        [sg.Text('Ваш файл:', size=(20, 1))],
        [sg.InputText(key='ADDITIONAL_FILE', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
        [sg.Button(button_text='Выполнить')]]
```

Change of interfaces

```
def change_interfase(self, mode):
        if mode == COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH:
            window = sg.Window('LTA (localization translator assistant)', INTERFACE.ADD_FILE_ENG)
        elif mode == COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_RUSSIAN:
            window = sg.Window('LTA (localization translator assistant)', INTERFACE.ADD_FILE_RU)
```

A function that sets the initial interface

```
def get_default_interface(self):
        return sg.Window('LTA (localization translator assistant)', INTERFACE.DEFAULT, size=(700, 100))
```

Switching windows

```
interface = work_with_interface.get_default_interface()

while True:
    try:
        event, values = interface.read()
        #print(event, values) #debug
        if event in (None, 'Exit', 'Cancel'):
            break
        elif event =='MODE':
            interface.Close()
            interface = work_with_interface.change_interfase(values['MODE'])
```

This code works until I select the same option in sg.Combo. Then the code breaks down and throws the following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8vAA.png)
Please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements in `INTERFACE.ADD_FILE_ENG`, `ADD_FILE_RU` and `INTERFACE.DEFAULT` initialized once, can be used only once. So you need to create function to reinitialze all elements.

if you want get layout by calling function

```py
...
    def add_file_eng(self):
        return [
            [sg.Combo(values=list_commands, key='MODE', default_value=COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH, size=(85, 1), enable_events=True)],
            [sg.Text('Оригинальный файл:', size=(20, 1))],
            [sg.InputText(key='GENERAL_PATH', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
            [sg.Text('Ваш файл:', size=(20, 1))],
            [sg.InputText(key='ADDITIONAL_FILE', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
            [sg.Button(button_text='Выполнить')],
        ]
...
    def change_interfase(self, mode):
            if mode == COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH:
                window = sg.Window('LTA (localization translator assistant)', INTERFACE().add_file_eng())
...
```

or by the attribute

```py
...
    @property
    def add_file_eng(self):
        return [
            [sg.Combo(values=list_commands, key='MODE', default_value=COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH, size=(85, 1), enable_events=True)],
            [sg.Text('Оригинальный файл:', size=(20, 1))],
            [sg.InputText(key='GENERAL_PATH', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
            [sg.Text('Ваш файл:', size=(20, 1))],
            [sg.InputText(key='ADDITIONAL_FILE', size=(55, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(size=(10, 1), button_text='Обзор'), ],
            [sg.Button(button_text='Выполнить')],
        ]
...
    def change_interfase(self, mode):
            if mode == COMMANDS.ADDITIONAL_ENGLISH:
                window = sg.Window('LTA (localization translator assistant)', INTERFACE().add_file_eng)
...
```